# Quiz app security in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, security, apk

I am new to android and I am developing a quiz app which can be used for any topic of exams. It reads encrypted xml file and insert it into database then the students can take exam on their cellphone . The main problem which I am facing with is that a student can take exam and if the result wasnot good can easily uninstall it then reinstall it and then re-take exam and improve his/her quiz result . What can be done in order to prevent this bug in your opinion?! Thanks in advance.

Comment: An unique id can be assign to each user to prevent such a problem

Comment: That's not the only problem I guess. How would you prevent several students working together?

Comment: @Henry good call

Comment: @MCZ . please explain your idea a little more . tnx

Comment: @Henry . every quiz has random questions through a lot of questions with 30 seconds for each question and if the quiz will be done in a place with observation this may not be a problem .

Comment: one solution will be implementing a system which require authentication (user identity ), in this case you can keep track of each user activity and change state of each behavior (state pattern)